# Where did everything go in Nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

well this is most frustrating

In what used to be called Nautilus

Where is the drop down to allow me to select the view I want ?

Where is the right click --> make new folder gone in list view when the window is full ?

I used to do 
   sudo Nautilus 
to change chmod and owner - no Nautilus so what is it now called ?

Comment: it's still `nautilus` (case sensitive). in other words, typing `Nautilus` into a terminal will return a not-found error. also, since nautilus is graphical (not commandline) you should be using `gksu` instead of `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gnome-devs have *tidied* the code and the interface when they moved from gnome-2 to gnome-3.

With this *tidy*, you'll have to learn some new tricks.

Thus - there is no longer a drop-down to select the view you want.  The keyboard shortcuts are:

- icons <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- list <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- compact <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

As you can guess - this tidy as affected the list view & new create folder trick.  Use your newly learned shortcut to switch to icon-view and then you can create a new folder.  Alternatively - use the (old) keyboard shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

I'm not aware of any special function to "chmod" and "chown" - you can still right-click and choose properties and permissions.  You can then change the owner/group and file-access from that tab.

Remember to start `nautilus` as root using the command:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

or from the GUI:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

and then type `gksudo nautilus`

Comment: and of course - far too long playing with some other OS; I keep forgetting that this is a real OS (that works !) and everything is case sensitive :-)